# Elasticsearch version from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have access to Kibana version 7.3

From this GUI is there a way I can confirm which elasticsearch version it is on? I cannot assume that both components are running the same version.

See question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following API to get all nodes versions

```
GET _cat/nodes?v&h=ip,name,version,name,jdk
```

the output will be like the following picture
[image]

For more information and more options you can refer the following page:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html#cat-nodes-api-ex-headings

Answer (score 1):

you can simply run `GET /` from the dev-tools of kibana and it will show you the Elasticsearch cluster details. This is same as hitting the Elasticsearch from browser when you know the Elasticsearch host and port number, response will look like

```
{
"name": "Elasticsearch-cluster",
"cluster_name": "es_8.1.3",
"cluster_uuid": "-Z7M-1jiRqiRcy_0HnlBUA",
"version": {
"number": "8.1.3",
"build_flavor": "default",
"build_type": "tar",
"build_hash": "39afaa3c0fe7db4869a161985e240bd7182d7a07",
"build_date": "2022-04-19T08:13:25.444693396Z",
"build_snapshot": false,
"lucene_version": "9.0.0",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "7.17.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version": "7.0.0"
},
"tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```